# Scrapy X Path: can't concatenate expressions with "and"

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to extract all p nodes whose ancestor contains the word "content" in their id.

I have tried this:

```
//p and ancestor::div[contains(@id, 'content')]
```

Individually the tags work but I can't concatenate them.
Please help

The website is this one: https://www.accenture.com/us-en/success-airbus-wearable-technology

Answer (score 0):

This does the job:

```
//p[ancestor::div[contains(@id, 'content')]]/text()
```